# Is the "Lord's Prayer" (Matt 6:9-13, Luke 11:2-4) Jesus' version of the *Amidah?

Tags: prayer

The disciples asked Jesus to give them a prayer like John gave his disciples.  This seems to have been a practice of some of the rabbis in the years before and after Jesus.  Is this prayer Jesus' version of the "standing prayer"

**Amidah = "Standing Prayer"**

> The Amidah (Hebrew: תפילת העמידה, Tefilat HaAmidah, 'The Standing Prayer'), also called the Shemoneh Esreh (שמנה עשרה 'eighteen'), is the central prayer of the Jewish liturgy.
> <sub>(Source [Wikipedia: Amidah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidah))</sub>

> The Amidah is the core of every Jewish worship service, and is therefore also referred to as HaTefillah, or “The prayer.” Amidah, which literally means, “standing,” refers to a series of blessings recited while standing.
> <sub>(Source [My Jewish Learning: The Amidah](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/the-amidah/))</sub>

Comment: again, please include a more complete reference. Most readers here are not familiar with the Amidah.

Comment: I am not sure this is even a Biblical question because "Amidah" does not occur in the Bible.  Perhaps this should be asked on the Jewish site?

Comment: Please include explicit quotations of both "The Lord's Prayer" and "The Amidah" so that we can easily compare them. Each individual reader shouldn't have to look up what you are asking about. You can save everyone the trouble by doing it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may indeed have been a tradition in which the disciples of various first-century rabbis would ask their teachers to give them a model prayer. There is no known first-century version of the Admidah, but [the first blessing of the current version](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/full-text-of-the-first-blessing-of-the-amidah/) is as follows:

> Blessed are You, Lord our God and God of our ancestors God of Abraham, God of Isaac and God of Jacob, The great, mighty and awesome God, God most high Who bestows loving kindness and goodness and who creates everything  Who remembers the good deeds of the Patriarchs And who will lovingly bring a redeemer to their children’s children for the sake of His name King, Helper, Redeemer, and Shield Blessed are you
> Adonai, Shield of Abraham.

A fuller version of the Amidah is available [through this link](https://web.oru.edu/current_students/class_pages/grtheo/mmankins/drbyhmpg_files/GBIB766RabbLit/Chapter8Amidah/Chapter8Amidah3.html). It shares some themes with the Lord's prayer. For example, it says "We will sanctify Your Name in the world even as they (the angels) sanctify it in the heavens." This is echoed in Jesus' "hallowed by thy Name" and "thy will be done on earth as in Heaven."  The Amidah also includes an appeal for forgiveness, that reminds one of that found in the Lord's prayer.

> Forgive us, O our Father, for we have sinned. Pardon us, O our King, for we have transgressed, because You do pardon and forgive. Blessed are You, O Lord, who is gracious and forgives a multitude of wrongs.

The Lord's prayer, in asking God for the provision of daily bread, also calls to mind the Jewish version of table grace, the *ha-motzi*:

> Blessed are you, Lord our God, ruler of the universe who brings forth bread from the earth.

**Conclusion**: While there is no record of the Amidah itself existing in the first century, rabbis certainly taught their disciples how to pray and may have given them specific models. The versions of the Lord's prayer preserved in the Gospels constitute two examples, combining existing Jewish formulas with Jesus' unique emphasis on the coming Kingdom and the importance of forgiving others as the prerequisite of being forgiven by God.